# Firebase , como reproduzir um áudio no storage do firebase ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: android, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação , que ao clicar em um botão ele reproduz um áudio , porém se eu colocar todos os áudios no aplicativo , irá ficar muito pesado , teria como eu colocar no firebase esses áudios , e fazer com que ao clicar no botão ele reproduza utilizando o servidor do firebase ? 
Obrigado !

Comment: Qual linguagem você usa?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, é preciso saber como você está lidando com esses arquivos de `Áudio`.

Como você mesmo citou, **não é recomendável armazenar arquivos muito grandes** na aplicação, a pergunta é: você tem esses áudios pré-feitos ou você permite que o usuário crie esses áudios?

> Tenho áudios pré-criados

Felizmente o **Firebase** nos permite enviar arquivos para o **Storage** manualmente, fazendo assim:

- Acesse o painel do Firebase
- Vá até Storage e clique em fazer upload de arquivo

Você poderá enviar arquivos como: *Imagem*, *Áudio*, *Vídeo* e assim por diante... E eles ficaram armazenados no **Google Cloud Storage**.

Após ter feito o upload, você já poderá fazer o download por código, mas antes de irmos **à parte que interessa** é necessário fazer algumas coisinhas antes.

O **Firebase**, por padrão, não vai permitir que usuários sem autenticação acessem esses arquivos, isso significa que apenas usuário conectados com o **Firebase Auth** poderão baixar e enviar arquivos, mas claro, isso não é obrigatório, você pode configurar essas regras no próprio painel. Isso, claro, se você desejar que usuários não autenticados possam baixar os arquivos.

Para começar a modificar as regras do **Firebase Storage**, você pode começar por [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start). Ele nos dá um exemplo de como as regras podem ser:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firbase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Essa regra significa que apenas **usuários autenticados** poderão ler e enviar arquivos para o **armazenamento**. Para permitir que usuários não-autenticados enviem e leiam os arquivos, façamos:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firbase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Para editar suas regras, veja isto: [Firebase#EditarRegras](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#editar_regras)

Pronto, seguido os passos acima, poderemos fazer o **[download](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)** dos seus arquivos de áudio e executá-los por stream, que é a parte que nos interessa.

O que você precisa saber é: não iremos fazer o download do arquivo para o armazenamento local, podemos executar o arquivo diretamente por **StreamUrl**. 
Iremos fazer um pedido para que o **Firebase** retorne a Url de **Stream** do arquivo de áudio, feito isso, enviaremos para o **Media Player** reproduzir o arquivo.

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

private Button reproduceAudio;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_audio);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    reproduceAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_reproduce_audio);
    reproduceAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Primeiro vamos intanciar o FirebaseStorage para que possamos receber os links dos arquivos
            final FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

            /* Agora podemos pegar a referência do nosso arquivo de áudio
               podem ser múltiplos arquivos, para isso, consulte a documentação do firebase
               O caminho do seu arquivo de áudio estará disponível no console */

            StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("audios/my_file_cool_audio"); 
            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    final String audioUrl = uri.toString();

                    // enviar como parâmetro para o método sendUrlToMediaPlayer()
                    sendUrlToMediaPlayer(audioUrl);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Audio Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

void sendUrlToMediaPlayer(String url) {
    try {
        // enviar a StreamUrl para o player
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)

        // esperar que ele fique pronto e após ficar pronto tocar o áudio
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e("Audio Error", err.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Isto é basicamente o que você precisa para executar áudios remotamente utilizando o Firebase Storage. Se deseja ir mais a fundo, como por exemplo, fazer o download dos arquivos e armazená-los no dispositivo, você vai precisar disto: [Firebase#DownloadFiles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

Comment: Luc , ta dando erro nessa linha mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

Comment: no log aparece assim error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnPreparedListener

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: mas , como o aplicativo vai saber que to pegando do meu firebase? onde que eu configuro para buscar direto no meu storage?

Comment: Quando você configura o Android Studio com o Firebase, ele já fica conectado ao seu Firebase.

Comment: A menos que tu não tenha configurado, é claro. É só editar essa linha: `firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("audios/my_file_cool_audio");`

Comment: Ele aponta pra tua database, e claro, tu deve colocar o caminho certo do arquivo(s)

Comment: Aqui não deu certo nao , o app fecha , mas vou dar uma pesquisada , obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eu não sei como tu configurou o app com o firebase, pelo android studio da pra fazer automaticamente. Isso foi mais um guia, te recomendo olhar os links da resposta!

Comment: Eu só liguei na conta só , blz valeu

Comment: Olá!
E se eu quiser fazer o streamming disso em uma aplicação web, serve também?